# Pear Mail won't send if From header has scandinavian characters

Tags: php, email, pear

Imagine the following:

```
$from = "Testäöå <example@example.com>";
....
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject,
    'MIME-Version' => "1.0",
    'Content-type' => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

If the $from variable is just `"Test <example@example.com>"`, script works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're specifying the headers directly, you need to escape them manually. Only ASCII characters are allowed in headers, so you need to escape them.

You can do that i.e. with

```
'=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($from).'?='
```

Alternatively, you can use the Multibyte string functions as described in the comments of http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php :

```
$encodedFrom = mb_encode_mimeheader($from, 'UTF-8', 'Q');
```